# Remove ALL User generated Files from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, powershell, user-accounts, file-management

I have a question about file/program handling in windows 10.

My Problem is that i will leave my company at the end of the month and want to clean out my windows user account. I know when i delete the user on this device all documents and such get delete but i think this only effects the data which is stored in the User Profile. My Problem is that i have 3 drives which have to be cleaned of all data generated by my user. Call me paranoid, but sometimes i did private stuff during downtime, which nobody has to know about.

In addition we are only a small company and therefore we dont have a IT department, which wipes the machines clean, so if i want to ensure my data is gone i have to do it myself.

I think going over every folder can be quite tedious, and there must be a better way to do that.

What i would need is:

- a way to display all files generated by my user
- a way to display all installed programs by my user (some of those can stay on the system, but some might have to go)

If you have any suggestions how i could generate those lists, i can continue from there with a small powershell script to delete the files and folders. And to remove the unnecessary programs.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

To look for files created by you, you could examine the [System.FileOwner](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-fileowner) property, a string in the format `<ComputerName>\<UserName>`, and filter on that.

You can first display the property in a **File Explorer** `Details` view to see if it suits your needs:
[image]

If that suits your needs and you want to access the property in **PowerShell**, use the [ExtendedProperty()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty) method of the `FolderItem` object. Open a **PowerShell** console and run this code to obtain a filter you can pipe `FIleSystemInfo` ubjects to:

```
$OwnerPropID = '{9B174B34-40FF-11D2-A27E-00C04FC30871},4'
$OwnerText   = '{0}\{1}' -f $env:ComputerName , $env:UserName
$Shell       = New-Object -ComObject shell.application


Filter Select-MyFiles {
    If ( $shell.NameSPace(( $_.DirectoryName)).ParseName($_.Name).ExtendedProperty($OwnerProp) -eq $OwnerText ) {$_}
}
```

Then use with the output of `Get-ChildItm`:

```
gci -af -s -ea silent | Select-MyFiles
```

Preliminary testing shows COM errors popping up:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:10
+     If ( $shell.NameSPace(( $_.DirectoryName)).ParseName($_.Name).Ext ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Not sure which method is throwing this, but I still think it's a valid starting point.

Comment: Thanks Keith for the tip i get the same exception as you with the script, but the files it self work like i charm (deleted nearly 200GB =D), if we could fix the script i would accept this answer